# PHPExcel Multiple worksheet formula returning PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception

Tags: php, phpexcel

Goodevening,

I'm using the PHPExcel Library to populate an existing Excel sheet with some data, and show the result of the calculated value on a webpage.

I've got a couple of formulas that look like this:
`=IF(OR($B$7=$A$17;$B$8=$A$17;$B$9=$A$17);"";B9)`

`=IF(B12<=B14;IF(B12=A17;A17;VLOOKUP(CEILING(B12;1);'Motor selection'!$1:$1048576;2;FALSE));A17)`

I get the following error when I try to get the calculated value of 'B9' for example:
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Pump selection!D7 -> Pump selection!B9 -> Formula Error: An unexpected error occured' in includes/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php:291`

I'm using the following PHP code, which is pretty standard.

```
$objType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($objType);

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

// Populate values
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B4', 100)
        ->setCellValue('B5', 75);

// Motor
$motor = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B9')->getFormattedValue();
```

As I am not an Excel expert (a client sent me this) I have no clue what is going wrong or how to fix this. All I know is that the formulae in the sheet itself are working fine when I open it in Excel.

Would love to know if someone can assist me on this. I can share the complete Excel file if that's necessary.

Thanks in advance,

Kevin

Edit: I've read that the issues might have something to do with the dollar signs in the formula, and I've already tried escaping them with `\$` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Edit2: The file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HH3oCzLD5oknEzJtEnKj7ew5tLboqdPD/view?usp=sharing). Idea is that B4 and B5 of the first sheet get populated with form data, and the result will be in D7:H7.

Comment: If you use `getValue()` to return the formula, does it contain those `;` separators, or i it using a `,` for the function argument separator?

Comment: @MarkBaker It's using a `,`. I get the following results when I use `getValue()`

=IF(OR(\$B\$7=\$A\$17,\$B\$8=\$A\$17,\$B\$9=\$A\$17),"",B9)

=IF(B12<=B14,IF(B12=A17,A17,VLOOKUP(CEILING(B12,1),'Motor selection'!$1:$1048576,2,FALSE)),A17)

Comment: Well you don't want the "\" before the `$`, because that will cause problems

Comment: But debugging the formula as described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357) might help identify the cause of teh problem

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. I've tried that but forgot to remove it just now.

I get these when I use `getValue()`

=IF(B12<=B14,IF(B12=A17,A17,VLOOKUP(CEILING(B12,1),'Motor selection'!$1:$1048576,2,FALSE)),A17) 
=IF(OR($B$7=$A$17,$B$8=$A$17,$B$9=$A$17),"",B9)

Comment: Thanks for the gist. I've just added the function `testFormula` and got the following result:

`Formula Value is =IF(B12<=B14,IF(B12=A17,A17,VLOOKUP(CEILING(B12,1),'Motor selection'!$1:$1048576,2,FALSE)),A17)EOLExpected Value is M6-650-2 PARSER ERROR: Formula Error: An unexpected error occuredEOLParser Stack :-EOLEOL`

Comment: Is `$1:$1048576` missing a column reference? You might also want to reduce that range to avoid using too much memory, or taking too long to execute

Comment: As far as I can tell it isn't. Excel is not giving any errors and says that `'Motor selection'!$1:$1048576` is the table_array of VLOOKUP and also, the formula is working fine in the Excel program itself. I am not an Excel export though, so not sure about this. I've included the original Excel file in my question (see Edit2) if you want to take a look.

Comment: `$1:$1048576` may work in MS Excel but it won't work in PHPExcel, so that definitely has the potential to cause an error in the calculation when PHPExcel is trying to evaluate it.... Generally a range is represnted by `fromColumn, fromRow colon toColumn, toRow`. what's the range supposed to represent? It looks like the entire range of the worksheet: from A1 to XFD1048576.... I never knew you could select every single cell like that without referencing columns as well

Comment: I'd suggest modifying that range to `A1:D148` which is all the data you have in that worksheet, and see if that resolves the problem

Comment: I've modified the range, and now it's working fine. Will have a look at it when I am at the office since it has to be possible for the client to upload updated versions of the sheet. I think I can fix the cell value within PHP then. Thanks for your help!